# send mail to multiple users using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to send email to multiple users using php but encounter some issues.i can send fine to the email address but it shows all the email addresses in the to field. I would like it to a loop and send the email to each of the user separately.

my php code is

here I am grabbing all info from MYSQL.

```
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE USER_ID='$user_id");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($r);
$emailfrom=$r['EMAIL_FROM'];
$emailpriority=$r['EMAIL_PRIORITY'];
$emailsubject=$r['EMAIL_SUBJECT'];
$emailto=$r['EMAIL_TO']; --> data stored here is the email addresses of the users.
```

it is also formatted already -> example: test1@test.com,test2@test.com,test3@test.com etcc

email headers

```
$subject = "$emailsubject";
$mailer = "$emailfrom";
$headers = "From: $mailer \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $mailer\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Importance: $emailpriority\r\n";

mail($emailto, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you try separating email address using semi-colon instead of comma?

Comment: tried that, it does not send no email

Comment: Try parsing `$emailto` into an array of addresses. I've posted an answer depicting how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode) to parse each address in the string `$emailto` as an member of an array. Since your string is comma-delimited, you'll want to pass the string `','` as the first argument:

```
$addresses = explode(',', $emailto);
```

This results in an array of addresses, which you can loop through and execute `mail()` separately for each iteration:

```
foreach ($addresses as $recipient) {
    mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers); 
}
```

Comment: hi, I've tried that early but it's not sending emails. :(

Comment: You'll need to parse the string `$emailto` into an array of email addresses. I've updated my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through as said by [zeantsoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086529/zeantsoi) or you can use [PHPMailer](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/files/downloads/PHPMailer_5.2.0.zip) library and which suits your requirement better.

You can refer to the documentation [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).